# Document.links pega todos os links do website?

Tags: javascript, html

Gostaria de saber se o comando JS `document.links` pega todos os links do website ou apenas da pagina??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links), todos os elementos [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) com [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href) definido são listados pela função [`Document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links).

> [`Document.links`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/links)
>
> The `links` read-only property of the `Document` interface returns a collection of all [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) elements and [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) elements in a document with a value for the [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href) attribute.
>
> **Exemple**:
>
> ```
> var links = document.links;
> for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
>   var linkHref = document.createTextNode(links[i].href);
>   var lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
>   document.body.appendChild(linkHref);
>   document.body.appendChild(lineBreak);
> }
> ```

Em tradução livre:

> A propriedade somente leitura `links` da interface `Document` retorna uma coleção de todos os elementos [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) e elementos [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) de um documento com um valor para o atributo [`href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href).